# How to check the number of points <=10 in Cypress

Tags: cypress

```
cy.get('div[id="base-table-\[object\ Object\]-body"] > .MuiGrid-root, .jss505').should('have.length', 10)
```

How to make a check  <=10 ? Maybe to.have.length.most()
DOM

```
<div id="base-table-[object Object]-body">
    <div class = "MuiGrid-root jss505"> </div>
    <div class = "MuiGrid-root jss505"> </div>
    <div class = "MuiGrid-root jss505"> </div>
    <div class = "MuiGrid-root jss505"> </div>
    <div class = "MuiGrid-root jss505"> </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Is the 'number of points' text or bullet points? Also, it would help if you could add piece of the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can enhance the assertion as follows

```js
cy.get('div[id="base-table-\[object\ Object\]-body"] > .MuiGrid-root, .jss505')
  .should('have.length.lt', 11)
```

Comment: `have.length.lt` tests `< 10`, and `have.length.lte` tests `<=10`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following callback assertion

```js
cy.get('div[id="base-table-[object Object]-body"] > .MuiGrid-root, .jss505')
  .should($els => expect($els.length).to.be.lte(10))
```

Using `.should()` instead of `.then()` gives you command retry in async situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these assertions:

```js
cy.get('div[id="base-table-[object Object]-body"] > .MuiGrid-root, .jss505')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    expect(len).to.be.lte(10)
  })
```

Or,

```js
cy.get('div[id="base-table-[object Object]-body"] > .MuiGrid-root, .jss505')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    expect(len).to.be.within(0, 10)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!